# Redirect a request to different URL even if file exists

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Ok so I need to redirect all requests to javascript files to a compression system I have created.

so admin/js/_global.js would redirect to _lib/compress.php?file=admin/js/_global.js

I have tried the follow htaccess code located in the root of the site but it just doesn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin/js/(.*)\.js$ _lib/compress\.php?f=admin/js/$1\.js [R=301,L]
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : (don't forget to clear your browser cache)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(admin/js/.*\.js)$ _lib/compress.php?file=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: not working :(  browser cache was cleared as well.  Even redirect to a fake file so it would create 404 but nothing

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^admin/js/.*$  _lib/compress\.php?f=admin/js/$1\.js
```

Comment: didn't work still display original file not compressed version

Comment: Have you tested your compression system thorougly? (Not that I doubt you, but it's just odd :) )